# Writing to a file within a folder in C

Tags: c, file, directory

How can I do this?

I know opening a new file is something akin to this:

```
    fpcon=fopen("konf_in","w");
    printf("Whatever I want to input");
    fclose(fpcon);
```

The output file only needs to be a simple .txt or .dat file

Comment: fpcon=fopen("konf_in","w");

Comment: fpcon=fopen("/your folder/konf_in","w"); is it?

Comment: +1 for including source code -1 for not even trying it out. You could have answered your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write to a file, you need to call fprintf and pass your file pointer which is `fpcon`, see this example:

```
char name[20];
int  number;

FILE *f;
f = fopen("/your_folder/sample.txt", "w");

if (f == NULL) {
    printf("Error opening file!\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("\nNew contact name (max 19): ");
fgets(name, sizeof(name), stdin);

printf("New contact number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);    

fprintf(f, "%s - %d\n", name, number);
fclose(f);
```

This [page](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html) gives you further intel on how to handle file writes, appends, etc.

Just for clarification, the allowed modes for fopen are as follows:

- r  - open for reading
- w  - open for writing (file need not exist)
- a  - open for appending (file need not exist)
- r+ - open for reading and writing, start at beginning
- w+ - open for reading and writing (overwrite file)
- a+ - open for reading and writing (append if file exists)

Comment: It is safe to call `fgets()` with 20 (or, for that matter, `sizeof name`), since `fgets()` will read at most one less character than the size it is given, so that there's room for the terminating null character.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves hey thanks mate :), that doubt crossed my mind actually, I've corrected my answer with your advise.